# Changing type of a hasMany property in runtime

Tags: grails, groovy

In the following domain class:

```
class Quest {
    String name
    static hasMany = [ tasks : Task ]
}
```

is it possible to use ExpandoMetaClass (or any other mechanism!) to change `tasks` type, for example from `Set` to `List` in **runtime**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Use a `List` and cast it to `Collection`, if you need a `Set` or similar. Since you cannot make a `List` out of a `Set` without having a random order, this idea seems to go in the wrong direction.

Comment: I am developing a plugin, and actually I have not access to domain classes.

Comment: You cannot make a Set to a List without having random order of the domain objects. Therefore this way of solving your problem will fail unfortunately.

Comment: @Farshid modify the plugin and re-package it if it's a blocker

Comment: I was looking for leveraging dynamic power of groovy language for modifying domain classes, but it seems that domain classes have a static nature!